# Get value from each cell of a Range.Areas

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which I got [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/site/tip/creating_a_worksheet_map/)

```
Sub QuickMap()

    Dim FormulaCells
    Dim TextCells
    Dim NumberCells
    Dim Area

    If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub

'   Create object variables for cell subsets
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FormulaCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells _
      (xlFormulas, xlNumbers + xlTextValues + xlLogical)
    Set TextCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues)
    Set NumberCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
    On Error GoTo 0

'   Add a new sheet and format it
    Sheets.Add
    With Cells
        .ColumnWidth = 2
        .Font.Size = 8
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Do the formula cells
    If Not IsEmpty(FormulaCells) Then
        For Each Area In FormulaCells.Areas
            With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
                .value = "F"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End With
        Next Area
    End If

'   Do the text cells
    If Not IsEmpty(TextCells) Then
        For Each Area In TextCells.Areas
            With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
                .value = "T"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End With
        Next Area
    End If

'   Do the numeric cells
    If Not IsEmpty(NumberCells) Then
        For Each Area In NumberCells.Areas
            With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
                .value = "N"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End With
        End If
        Next Area
    End If
End Sub
```

What this code does is create a new `worksheet` with an map of other `worksheet`, for example, it place a N with background color yellow where is a numeric or constant on the other worksheet.

I want to set the background color to blue on cells on the map where the value on the other worksheet is a numeric and is greater than 130.

It seens to have a pretty simple solution but I have tried work with it like I work with `Ranges` but I am not getting any satisfactory results.

So, my question is,  how can I get the value of each cell to use a condition statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hereby a simple example:
`For Each c In Range("A1", "C3")
  If c.Value = "1" Then
...
`

Comment: I have this variable Area which I use to iterate over the Areas, but I cant use Area.Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop item on .area then if single item corresponding your text background cell will be blue otherwise yellow

```
Sub QuickMap()
        Dim FormulaCells
        Dim TextCells
        Dim NumberCells
        Dim Area

        If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub

    '   Create object variables for cell subsets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FormulaCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells _
          (xlFormulas, xlNumbers + xlTextValues + xlLogical)
        Set TextCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues)
        Set NumberCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
        On Error GoTo 0

    '   Add a new sheet and format it
        Sheets.Add
        With Cells
            .ColumnWidth = 2
            .Font.Size = 8
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '   Do the formula cells
        If Not IsEmpty(FormulaCells) Then
            For Each Area In FormulaCells.Areas
                With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
                    .Value = "F"
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End With
            Next Area
        End If

    '   Do the text cells
        If Not IsEmpty(TextCells) Then
            For Each Area In TextCells.Areas
                With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
                    .Value = "T"
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                End With
            Next Area
        End If

    '   Do the numeric cells
        If Not IsEmpty(NumberCells) Then
            For Each Area In NumberCells.Areas
                For Each Item In Area
                    If Item > 130 Then
                        ActiveSheet.Range(Item.Address).Value = "N"
                        ActiveSheet.Range(Item.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                    Else
                        ActiveSheet.Range(Item.Address).Value = "N"
                        ActiveSheet.Range(Item.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    End If
                Next Item
            Next Area
        End If
    End Sub
```